# Angular 2 change detection before and after service method is called

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, zone

I have a component that, when triggered by changed Input(), retrieves a new set of data from a service. I want my view to update before and after I retrieve the data. I've tried ngZone, ChangeDetectionRef, but nothing is working for me. Any suggestions appreciated!

**mycomponent.component.html**

```
  <p>{{ loading }}</p>
```

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```
  public loading: boolean;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes["mytrigger"]) {
      // WANT TO SET LOADING TO TRUE
      this.loading = true;
      this.myservice.getNewState().then((newState) => {
        // WANT TO SET LOADING TO FALSE
        this.loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

If I use NgZone, and place a debugger after each 'this.loading' statement, I can see the changes, but I can't see the changes in real time.

Comment: have you checked the diff of the timestamp before the service call and after it has finished.... i would guess that the time the service takes to process is too short to see the changes happening (maybe it is so fast the the view isn't even updated at all)

Comment: _but I can't see the changes in real time_ - what exactly can't you see?

Comment: you don't want to approach it this way.  Inject a service that exposes that loading variable as an observable and subscribe to it with async, then have your state retrieval service manipulate the loading observable.

Comment: @Nickolaus, the elapsed time is approx 1000ms

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, I see "false", as if the loading variable hasn't changed.

Comment: @bryan60, I tried that (I now have an @Input() loading variable that is populated by an async pipe of the loading service observable). However, the component is only detecting the second observable change. (If I print the observable changes in the loader service, I see TWO observable changes - one for true, one for false).

Comment: you don't want to put an observable in through an input, inject a service into a component directly.